# Django: login link to appear only when a user is logged in

Tags: python, django

I am making an app in django in which i have used the django built in authentication system. Both login and logout links are present in the navbar. I want to make the logout link appear only when the user has logged in and not at all times. How do i do that?

code snippet of `project/urls.py`:

```
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^login/$', views.login, {'template_name': 'login.html', 'authentication_form': LoginForm}, name='login'),
url(r'^logout/$', views.logout, {'next_page': '/home'}), ]
```

code snippet of `login.html`;

```
<div class="container">
    <section id="content">

        {% if form.errors %}
            <p>Your username and password didn't match. Please try again.</p>
        {% endif %}

        {% if next %}
            {% if user.is_authenticated %}
                <p>Your account doesn't have access to this page. To proceed,
                    please login with an account that has access.</p>
            {% else %}
                <p>Please login to see this page.</p>
            {% endif %}
        {% endif %}

        <form action="{% url 'login' %}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
            <h1>Login Form</h1>

            <div class="imgcontainer">
                <img src="{% static 'student/patient.jpg' %}" alt="Avatar" class="avatar">

            </div>

            <div class="username">
                {{ form.username.label_tag }}
                {{ form.username }}                 
            </div>

            <div class="password">
                {{ form.password.label_tag }}
                {{ form.password }}
            </div>

            <div class="submitb">
                <input type="submit" value="Log In" name="mybtn">

            </div>

            <div class="resetb">
                <input type="submit" value="Reset">
                <a href="#forgotpwd">Forgot password?</a>

            </div>

            <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}" />




        </form>
```

code snippet of `base.html`(only the navbar is shown):

```
<ul>
  <li><a class="active" href="/home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="/about">About </a></li>
  <li><a href="/signup">Sign up</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Doctor's login</a></li>
  <li><a href="{% url 'login' %}?next={{request.path}}">Patient's login</a></li>
  <li><a href="#about">FAQs</a></li>
   <li><a href="/contact">Contact us</a></li>
   <li><a href="#about">Reviews</a></li>
   <li><a href="/logout">Logout</a></li>
</ul>
```

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Put the logout list item in an *if* block that checks that the user is authenticated like so:

```
<ul>
...
{% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
  <li><a href="/logout">Logout</a></li>
{% endif %}
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Although using the variable `request.user.is_authenticated` is one way. To make it simpler create HTML pages such that login and logout button are **disintegrated**.

Pages which appear after **login** should only contain the **logout** option/button. This will smoothen your development process.